# Não estou conseguindo mudar o tamanho e a cor do botão input tipo submit:

Tags: html, css

```css
   input [type=submit] { //esse comando não ta funconando 
 background-color: #111f66; 
 border: none;
```

```html
 <form method="POST" action="processa.php"  >
  <input type="email" name="" placeholder="Usuário" >
  <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Senha" >
  <input type="submit" value="ACESSAR"/>   //esse botão
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu erro é que vc deixou um espaço quando declarou a propriedade, entre a palavra `input` e as chaves `[]` não deve ter espaço

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa forma como vc escreveu o comentário no CSS com dupla barra `//` tb não é aconselhável, no CSS para escrever comentários use `/* seu comentário aqui */`

```css
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #111f66;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="processa.php">
  <input type="email" name="" placeholder="Usuário">
  <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Senha">
  <input type="submit" value="ACESSAR" />
</form>
```

Comment: Vlw obrigado! consegui aqui

Comment: @gobiraaaa cara se vc acha que respondeu a pergunta considere marca-la como aceita marcando esse ícone ✔ logo a abaixo das setinhas da minha resposta. Assim sua pergunta não fica pendente sem resposta aceita  sendo que já resolveu []´s